# Create SQL Server schema in Node js is giving a error sql.alienSchema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, sql-server

This is the code which I am getting an error with. Please help me to resolve.

```
const sql= require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const alienSchema= new sql.alienSchema(
    {
        name:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        tech:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        subscription:
        {
            type:Boolean,
            require:true,                
        }        
    }
)   


module.exports= alienSchema;  //exporting
```

Comment: this is the error   -> sql.alienSchema is not a constructor

Comment: Please add the full and exact error message to your question by editing it. Also, provide your debugging attempts

Comment: const sql= require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');



 const alienschema= 
{
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    tech:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    subscription:
    {
        type:Boolean,
        require:true,
        
    }
}



module.exports= alienschema;      This solved my issue

Comment: Please add all information to the question by editing it